# Using PHP function to solve for a missing numbers

Tags: php, function, formula, equation

I have a pool of 16 numbers 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768. I have a number that is comprised of some combination of the 16 numbers using 1 - 16 of them added up.  For example I have a number 671 which is made by 1+2+4+8+16+128+512. I am trying to figure out a way to take my pool of 16 numbers and my total number and identify which numbers were used to make that total number. I will be using php to do this how ever I have tried searching and math is far from my strong suit I have come up empty trying to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: simple decimal to binary converter. it is just a matter of substractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

[image]

You can have a simple back trace to achieve this

```
echo "<pre>";
$ns = array(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768);
print_r(subsetSum($ns, 671 ));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 128 + 512
)
```

Function Used

```
function subsetSum($arr, $val, $i = 0) {
    $r = array();
    while($i < count($arr)) {
        $v = $arr[$i];
        if($v == $val)
            $r[] = $v;
        if($v < $val)
            foreach(subsetSum($arr, $val - $v, $i + 1) as $s)
            $r[] = "$v + $s";
        $i++;
    }
    return $r;
}
```